# Pass 'this' into C API callback taking void* user data

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I'm wrapping a C API with a C++/CLI wrapper in order to consume it from a C# project.
The C API requires a `callback` for one of its functions. The callback signature takes a `void*` user data parameter.

I would like to pass in `this` as the `void*` user data parameter to the C API but I have been unsuccessful (failing to compile). Furthermore it's not as easy to pass in 'this' as `this` is referring to a managed class, so of course I'd have to pin the reference first prior to passing it in.

I'm also unsure how to cast the `void*` parameter back to a `ManagedClass^` in the callback function.

Code:

```
public ref class ManagedClass
{
public:
    static void __stdcall CallbackFunc( int, void* userData )
    {
          // How can I cast the void* parameter back to
          // ManagedClass^ ??
    }

    void Open(  )
    {     
         // I know I need to pin the reference to myself
         // but I'm unsure how to go about it. How can I store
         // this in a pin_ptr??       
         ptr = this;

         // Open the third party C-API passing in
         // my callback function and a reference to
         // myself.
         thirdPartyApiOpen( &CallbackFunc, ptr );
    }   
 private:
    pin_ptr<ManagedClass^> ptr; 
};
```

Comment: That breaks the garbage collector, the compiler will always stop you from doing this.  The scenario is well supported in .NET, you need to declare a delegate for your callback and use Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() to generate the function pointer for the native code.  Examples abound, [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298225/pass-managed-function-pointer-as-unmanaged-callback).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a tracking handle as a void\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999592/passing-a-tracking-handle-as-a-void)